# Finding partial texts in Conditional Formatting, Custom formula is

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Using Conditional Formatting in Google Spreadsheets, C5:E120 gets a color from column H. The code with the custom formula is:

```
=$H:$H="mon"
```

Like this,

- when H5 is day `mon`, color goes yellow in C5:E5
- when H6 is day `tue`, color goes blue in C6:E6
- when H7 is day `wed`, color goes green in C7:E7

and so on. This works as expected.

But I've sometimes to mix days in ColumnH, like `sun mon wed`.

How can I look for part of the text in a cell?

I've tried several functions like find, lookup but can't get it working.

Comment: Ah, found it!
`=if(countif($H5;"*wed*");TRUE;FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems:

```
=if(countif($H5;"*wed*");TRUE;FALSE)
```

works for you but you may like to note that such formatting is *Conditional*, so this version as a formula:

```
=countif($H5;"*wed*")
```

should be adequate.

Comment: What do you mean, conditinal? Your version works also, but i'm willing to learn why your version is better ;'-)